# How to find the minimal value of this function under such constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$f(x,y)=x-\sqrt{y-x^2}$ with $a<x<b$ and $x^2<y<c*x-d$.
What I did is, first take partial derivative at $x$ and $y$ respectively, however, there is no critical point because fy is always smaller than 0.
Then the extreme values should be reached in the boundary. 
Thus, I consider $f(x,y)+\lambda*(y-x^2)$, and use the Lagrange approach to solve an equation system with respect to x,y, and lambda to work out the $(x_0,y_0)$ that gives the extreme values.
Is there something wrong in what I did?

Million thanks for answering my naive question!!

Comment: Not a naive question at all. Did you try calculating $f_x$?

Comment: yes, to find the critical point, I need $f_x=f_y=0$. though $f_x=0$ gives $x=(y/2)^1/2$, $f_y$ is always negative. So I suppose there is no critical point in this area and the extreme value can only be found in the boundary. No?

Comment: Indeed. Calculating $f_x$ will help you find the boundary point.

Comment: Could you please be more specifical? I know that $f_x=1 + x/\sqrt{-x^2 + y}$.

Comment: If I am correct (please check), $f_{xx}(\sqrt{y/2},y) >0$ therefore you have a minimum in $x$. So you know the minimal value will be on the line $x = \sqrt{y/2}$. Using this you can transformation your problem into a one variable problem, easier to solve.

Comment: I am not sure you are correct. If there is any critical point or stationary point, its derivative $f_x$ and $f_y$ should be both 0. I want to find the global minimal value in the whole area $a<x<b$ and $x2<y<c∗x−d$, thus I guess it should be on the boundary.

Comment: I didn't explain myself properly. It is not a minimum point but it is the minimum in $x$. Treating $y$ as a constant, $f$ is smallest when $x=\sqrt{y/2}$. Then along this line, you will find that when $f$ is smallest in $y$ setting $x = \sqrt{y/2}$. It will be on the boundary of $y$ as the derivative is non-zero. Of course, check $x$ is within the interval $[a,b]$, I forgot this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

hint:

first :find domain of $x$,with $x^2<cx-d$,(you need to discuss $c>0$ and $c<0,c=0$)

$f(x,y) \le x \implies f_{max}$ is the max of $x$

for min, user88595 already give  the result which means you can find $y$ to check when it is the best value in the domain of $y$.